# How to change column length if it has dependents

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `dbo.Items`:

```
[id] [bigint] [not null]
[Name] [nvarchar](200)
[Decription] [nvarchar](500)
```

Also about 15 `views` with using table `Items`, e.g: `ASM_V_ItemOrders`

so now, I'm going to change length:

```
alter table Items
   alter column Description nvarchar(1000) null
```

But, i get a lot of errors from views:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
> The object 'ASM_V_ItemOrders' is dependent on column 'Description'.

---

How to solve these problem via sql query?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh,  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17099.0

Comment: Are these indexed views?

Comment: @Wouter, yes, there are indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use indexed views then you will need to drop the view first. And recreate the view after the alter table.

*When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified.*

source: [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)